# `openssl digest | head -c 10` gives strange results

Tags: bash, openssl, hashing, coreutils, head

I'm using salted hashes of some memorable words as login/pass for anonymous accounts and just now I've noticed that sometimes I get no result for my method and then I've discovered that it was not working properly from the start. What I do is:

```
pc ~ % echo "A simple string." | openssl sha512 | head -c 10
(stdin)= f%
```

Surprisingly for me this only gives one character instead of 10 on Linux and Mac in bash and zsh. All `head -c`-ed hashes are of random length, but `head -n 1` prints the whole string correctly:

```
pc ~ % echo "A simple string." | openssl sha512 | head -n 10
(stdin)= f261768808d0b30162a8e412b3195ad1aa0fa21dfcf67968dd9f5050e919eee6bbbc2ce8845d80cb4930b478407e28e7d9f0d5750cbe069f17de5eff52060e54
```

Perhaps it uses threads, there is an encoding problem or I just don't understand stdio piping, but how do I fix the bug? It should just print an arbitrary hashed string trimmed to a fixed length. I'm also just curious about the reason of such behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm just really dumb. The prefix `(stdin)=`  is also a part of the piped string. If anyone needs to get rid of it, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42797/openssl-dgst-sha1-producing-an-extraneous-stdin-prefix-and-trailing-new.